# how to change website theme and save this theme so it doesn't change on reload?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I found a lot of website, that it allows me to change the website theme , without being logged in.

and when i refresh the page the theme doesn't reset. I was wondering how can i do that , or can someone put me on the right pass.

do i focus on the back-end , or it's only on front-end (client-side).

does it website to browser related. or it's something else ? i really looked a lot tried to save the the client choose into his db, but now when i see website that i can change it, without even being logged in so it's not related to db.

or is it session related ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the theme information in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) in your users' browsers. When the app starts you can check if there is any theme information in the `localStorage` and use that, and when you update the theme you can set it in `localStorage`.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    theme: localStorage.getItem("theme") || "red"
  };

  toggleTheme = () => {
    this.setState(
      ({ theme }) => ({
        theme: theme === "red" ? "green" : "red"
      }),
      () => {
        localStorage.setItem("theme", this.state.theme);
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.theme }}>
        <div>Welcome to my website</div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleTheme}> Toggle theme </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this in Reactjs (obviously you would need to implement the MyTheme and SelectInput components yourself):

```
class MyReactComp extends React.Component {

    setTheme(theme) {
        localStorage.setItem('theme', selectedTheme);
    }
    render() {
        <MyThemeLayout theme={localStorage.getItem('theme')} />
        <MySelectInput onChange={theme => this.setTheme(theme)} />
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you could send the theme choice to the backend, store it in MongoDB or something and then set an ID cookie so that the theme can be retrieved when the user next visits the site.